# SolidWorks - Creating Part file from a STEP file

Tags: solidworks, solidworksapi

I am a beginner with SolidWorks. I want to know how to find an API that lets me create a SolidWorks part file from a STEP file that I have with me. Please share some pointers.

Thanks,
Pavan.

Answer (score 2):

Basically you open the step file with

```
OpenDoc6 Method (ISldWorks)
```

and then save it to the solidworks file type you want.

```
Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc
swModel.Extension.SaveAs(swxFilenaam, 0, swSaveAsOptions_e.swSaveAsOptions_Silent, Nothing, lErrors, lWarnings)
```

There is a complete example that handles filetypes, target subfolder and batch on this link:
[Example](https://edalsolutions.be/index.php/nl-NL/automatisatie/vba-macro-s/47-import-step-files-with-batch)

Comment: In the example you provided, you dont use the OpenDoc6 method. Can you please add some snippet on how to use this method to open a STEP file?.